# How can I save my data that goes from one ViewController to another?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, save, userdefaults

I am trying to build an todo/reminder application. I have come some way but I am stuck in this "saving" step. I have two viewControllers. One for where I am register my task and one for where to store these tasks. This works fine but as soon as I relaunch the app it goes away. I have seen many tutorials and descriptions on how to solve this but none for my kind of case where I need to call a "save-method" on the tap-on-button on one VC and then store/load these in a tableview in another VC.

Is there anyone out there who have some tips or links for where I can read about this, or any ideas of how I could solve this?

Here is how the views look (very simple).

The View where you registered, the data in the fields are being saved:

[image: The View where you registered, the data in the fields are being saved]

The second Vc with the TableView which store the data:

[image: The second Vc with the TableView which store the data]

Here are some code for the first Vc (the one from where you add/register a new task):

```
//
//  ViewControllerNew.swift
//  easy reminder 2
//
//  Created by Andreas Sjöstedt on 2019-02-04.
//  Copyright © 2019 Andreas Sjöstedt. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewControllerNew: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var TaskTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var todaysdate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var currenttime: UILabel!

    @IBAction func timeSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {
        currenttime.text = String(Int(sender.value))
    }

    @IBAction func SavedButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        ToDoController.addTodo(newTodo: TaskTextField.text! + " " + currenttime.text! + " " + todaysdate.text!)
        // code for add the data in TableView on Edit Site
    }

    var LableTTF = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getCurrentDate()
        // the current date text//

        getSingle()
        // acces the calendar//

        getCurrentTime()
        // the current time lable//

        TaskTextField.delegate = self
        // the task-text-lable//

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MyNoteName"), object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (Notification) in
            let dateVc = Notification.object as! ViewControllerDate
            self.todaysdate.text = dateVc.formattedDate
            // notification reciever
        }
    }

    func getCurrentDate(){
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        //formatter.timeStyle = .medium
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        let str = formatter.string(from: Date())
        todaysdate.text = str
        // code for showing current date //
    }

    func getCurrentTime(){
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        let str = formatter.string(from: Date())
        currenttime.text = str
        // code for showing current time //
    }

    func getSingle(){
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        _ = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
        _ = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
        _ = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
        // code for access the calendar //// code for passing the data to other view //
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        TaskTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
        //Hide keyboard when press "klar"//
    }
}
```

And here are some code for the other Vc (which contains the TableView where the data is getting stored:

```
//
//  ViewControllerEdit.swift
//  easy reminder 2
//
//  Created by Andreas Sjöstedt on 2019-02-04.
//  Copyright © 2019 Andreas Sjöstedt. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewControllerEdit: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
        super.viewDidAppear( animated )
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return ToDoController.todosArray.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = ToDoController.todosArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
            ToDoController.removeTodo(atIndex:  indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry, here are some code for the ToDo controller as well, if that is where to add this funcion:

```
    //
//  ToDoController.swift
//  easy reminder 2
//
//  Created by Andreas Sjöstedt on 2019-02-12.
//  Copyright © 2019 Andreas Sjöstedt. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ToDoController: NSObject {

    static var todosArray:Array<String> = []

    class func addTodo( newTodo:String){
        ToDoController.todosArray.append(  newTodo)
    }

    class func removeTodo(atIndex:Int) {
        ToDoController.todosArray.remove(at: atIndex)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving data in ToDoController, but you didn't mentioned its code here. The problem must be in it. You might not be saving data in ToDoController. Your ToDoController keep data until the app remains active. When you kill the app your controller de-allocated and though the data. If you want persistent data you have to use Plist, Userdefaults or Coredata. For persistent data please see [link](https://medium.com/@imranjutt/data-persistence-in-ios-2804d04bde62).

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot! I will have a look at this asap!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement protocol delegate for this issue, Use this code to get a solution for this, I hope it helps you.

```
import UIKit

protocol ViewControllerNewDelegate {
    func callBackFromViewControllerNew(_ myData:[String:Any])
}

class ViewControllerNew: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    weak var delegate: ViewControllerNewDelegate?


    @IBAction func SavedButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // code for add the data in TableView on Edit Site
        delegate.callBackFromViewControllerNew(//Pass dictionary here)
    }

}
```

Note:- defin ViewControllerNewDelegate, write callBackFromViewControllerNew function and don't forgot to write **delegte = self** when goto ViewControllerNew

```
class ViewControllerEdit: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ViewControllerNewDelegate {

    func goToViewControllerNew (){
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerNew") as! ViewControllerNew
        vc.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }    

    func callBackFromViewControllerNew(_ myData:[String:Any]){
        print(myData) // get data here from ViewControllerNew
    }        
}
```

Comment: Oh.. thanks!! Awesome! I will look into this ! Many thanks!

Comment: no I haven't.. I got stuck in the Core Data solution... =)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the persistence of your storing method.

```
static var todosArray:Array<String> = []
```

This is recreated every time, the app is started while losing all its values. It can't outlive your app. You need to write todos into a file or a database.

There are several options for it: Core Data, sqlite database, `UserDefaults`. The last one is the least appropriate solution here, however it's also the easiest to implement and I guess that's what you want for now.

```
extension UserDefaults {

    private static let todoKey = "ToDoKey" // name under which todo data are stored

    func addTodo(_ todo: String, date: Date) {
        var todos = allTodos() // mutable reference to be able to change its content
        todos.append((todo, date))

        set(todos, forKey: UserDefaults.todoKey)
    }

    func removeTodo(at index: Int) {
        guard index < numberOfTodos() else { return }

        var todos = allTodos()
        todos.remove(at: index)

        set(todos, forKey: UserDefaults.todoKey)
    }

    func todoValue(at index: Int) -> String? {
        guard index < numberOfTodos() else { return nil }

        return allTodos()[index].0 // retrieve the first value of a tuple
    }

    func todoDate(at index: Int) -> Date? {
        guard index < numberOfTodos() else { return nil }

        return allTodos()[index].1 // retrieve the second value of a tuple
    }

    func numberOfTodos() -> Int {
        return allTodos().count
    }

    private func allTodos() -> [(String, Date)] {
        let todos = object(forKey: UserDefaults.todoKey) as? [(String, Date)]
        return todos ?? [(String, Date)]()
    }

}
```

With that you can replace your static array as follows:

```
class ToDoController: NSObject {

    class func addTodo( newTodo:String) {
        UserDefaults.standard.addTodo(newTodo, Date())
    }

    class func removeTodo(atIndex:Int) {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeTodo(at: atIndex)
    }
}
```

To ask for a specific todo:

```
UserDefaults.standard.todoValue(at: index)
UserDefaults.standard.todoDate(at: index)
```